# Opening .EST files in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I was recently provided interpolated water quality data. However, it was provided to me in the .EST format.

I am able to open in any editor program ( R, notebook, etc..).

Is there a way to open these files in ArcGIS Pro?

[image: Screenshot of data]

Comment: It's an ASCII file. You can "open" it in ArcGIS just like you can in any other application. To *use* it would require a parser, and documentation of the what the file's data represents.